# Multiplying factors received through a SELECT JOIN command

Tags: join

I use a MYSQL command as follows:

```
UPDATE TABLE 1 FROM TABLE1 JOIN TABLE2 USING (COLUMN1)
SET TABLE1.AMOUNT = TABLE1.AMOUNT * TABLE2.FACTOR
```

According to this JOIN, there should be 3 rows returned from TABLE2 (say with factos 2, 3 and 4) but the TABLE1.AMOUNT only multiply the FACTOR in the first row and not the 2nd and 3rd row.

I expect to get the original AMOUNT x (2x3x4) BUT I get the value AMOUNT x 2

How do I solve this? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `UPDATE` statement only updates a given row once. You need to replace `TABLE2` with a subquery that produces the right multiplier. Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't have any multiplicative counterpart to `SUM` for multiplying a group of values together, but if you can accept some extra roundoff error, I suppose you could write:

```
UPDATE table1
  FROM table1
  JOIN ( SELECT column1,
                EXP(SUM(LN(table2.factor))) AS total_factor
           FROM table2
          GROUP
             BY column1
       ) subquery2
 USING (column1)
   SET table1.amount = table1.amount * subquery2.total_factor
;
```

(using the fact that Π*a*<sub>*k*</sub> = *e*<sup>Σln*a*<sub>*k*</sub></sup>).

Comment: @user3192489: You're welcome! This is the principle that allows a slide rule to be used for multiplication.